# How is x++ different from ++x?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm currently going through the Dynamics AX 2012 X++ developer E-learning and have a question about the X++ language that is not obvious from the documentation.

In one place it says that `x++` and `++x` are exactly the same. However it also has this statement where it talks about [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa594120.aspx):

> 1. postfix operators [] . ( params )  expr ++  expr --
> 2. unary operators ++ expr  -- expr  + expr  - expr  ~ !

So are they equivalent except for operator precedence or am I misunderstanding something?

Or does the fact that ++/-- are only used in statements and not expressions render all of this completely [irrelevant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc967420.aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to X++ documentation.  The "++" operator can only be used as a statement.   This restriction effectively trumps any operator precedence rules.   My interpretation is that the "++" operator was included in the X++ precedence documentation for completeness.